# Swift Annotation on Map as Button

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, annotations

I try to give my annotation 3 buttons (2 already done), Button 1 and Button 2 on the image work, now i want to perform a segue once Button 3 is clicked is there anyway to do so?

[image]

To create this Annotation my code look like

```
if (annotation is CustomPointAnnotation2){

            let reuseId = "ParseAnno"

            var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
            if anView == nil {
                anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                anView!.canShowCallout = true
            }
            else {
                anView!.annotation = annotation
            }

            let buttonSignIcon1 = UIButton()
            buttonSignIcon1.frame.size.width = 50
            buttonSignIcon1.frame.size.height = 52
            buttonSignIcon1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.373, blue: 0.694, alpha: 1.0)
            buttonSignIcon1.setImage(UIImage(named: "annotationButtonLeft"), forState: .Normal)
            anView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = buttonSignIcon1





            let buttonSignIcon = UIButton()
            buttonSignIcon.frame.size.width = 50
            buttonSignIcon.frame.size.height = 52
            buttonSignIcon.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
            buttonSignIcon.setImage(UIImage(named: "annotationButtonRight"), forState: .Normal)
            anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = buttonSignIcon

            let x = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation2
            anView!.image = UIImage(named:x.imageName)


            return (anView)
```

to "run a function" on tap i use

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        if control == annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView {

            print(annotationView.annotation?.title)
            print(annotationView.annotation?.coordinate)
            self.Destination_fromAnnotation = (annotationView.annotation?.coordinate)!
            self.getDirections()
        }
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to give button "3" also a action?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be advisable to give your `MKAnnotationView` a subview that holds the buttons.

If you can do with the left and right callout accessories as well as the `image` property, you are fine, but if you need more as in your case it is certainly better to embed all in a view that you design rather than relying on preconfigured UI elements that most likely were meant for something different.

In fact, your screenshot looks kind of crappy despite all its tricolor glory because of sloppy alignment and spacing, a case in point for a custom view.